# Read date field from excel with Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read a `Date` value from an excel sheet in java code using:

```
DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)
```

But it throws an exception saying `cannot read text from a numeric field`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us some code / the actual Exception being thrown.  Without that information, it's much harder to help you diagnose & solve your issue.

Comment: `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)` can return a boolean value: either true or false, how you are going to find the date from it. Share some code with us.

Answer (score 5):

You can check this using following and then use as per your requirement.

```
if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
        } else {
            System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted` method assumes you've already checked that the cell is a numeric value. See the code http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.openl.rules/org.openl.lib.poi.dev/5.8.0/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.java#DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29

Since Excel stores dates as numbers internally, verify that the cell is numeric first and then check if it is a date.

Then you can get the actual date value with this or something similar:

```
Date date = HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(cell.getNumberValue());
```